# Operaciones con listas y escritura con formato, Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Me he visto envuelto en una serie de dudas, a la hora de realizar operaciones con listas, llevo un par de días, dándole vueltas, pero cada vez que avanzo un poco, me vuelven a surgir dudas, espero me puedan ayudar.

Después de leer varios archivos, **.HDF5** y **.NetCDF**, obtengo las siguientes listas, las cuáles las he aplanado y formateado para obtener sus valores.

```
listaA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,10000]
listaB = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,10000]
listaC = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,.......,10000]
```

Una vez tengo mis datos en 3 listas, creo la cabecera de salida.

```
# Cadenas fijas
cabecera = '  Res   A     B      C      \n'
unidades = '   m   (m)   (m)    (m)     \n'
output = ""
out = ""
```

Los resultados los almacenare en **lista_Res**:

```
# Creación de lista para almacenar los resultados
lista_Res = []
long = len(listaA)

op = 1200
for i in range(1,long):
    op -= (listaA[i]/listaA[i - 1]) + (2 + ((listaB[i-1]+listaB[i])/2)) / (c * d)
    lista_Res.append(round(op,3))
```

Aquí es donde estoy atascado, en principio esto lo que hace es, tomo como valor inicial **1200** y se lo resto a la operación, de modo que el primer valor es **1200** y se va realizando la operación de forma iterativa hasta alcanzar la longitud de la **listaA**, los resultados los almaceno en **lista_Res**, esto en principio me servía, pero ahora necesito que el primer valor siga siendo **1200**, pero que se realice la operación durante **50** lineas o valores, entonces debe parar y volver a tomar como valor inicial **1200** durante otros **50** valores, de esta manera hasta recorrer toda la lista, de momento estoy atascado con esto.

Por último uno las listas para exportarlas en un **.txt**:

```
dirFich = '/path/salida.txt'
# Unión de las listas para exportarlas como .txt
for j in zip(lista_Res, listaA, listaB, listaC):
    name = str(len(range(0,long))) + ".txt"
    salida = open(dirFich + name,'w')
    out = ("{:> 19}" "{:> 13}" "{:> 19}".format(*j))
    print(out)
    output += out + '\n'
    #salida.write(cabecera) 
    #salida.write(unidades)  
    salida.write(output)  
    salida.close()
```

Aquí tendría que exportar en **4** columnas, en un **.txt** distinto cada **50** filas o valores, de momento al solo poder realizar una operación iterativa a lo lago de toda la lista, solo obtengo un **.txt**, pero debería poder obtener tantos **.txt** como operaciones se han realizo, como cada lista almacena **10.000** valores debería obtener **200 .txt**.
Espero me puedan ayudar, un saludo.

Digamos que la salida tendría que quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
Res       listA      listB       listC
1200         1           1          1
op           2           2          2
op           3           3          3
op           4           4          4
op           5           5          5
    .        .           .          .
    .        .           .          .
    .        .           .          .
   op        50          50         50
```

.txt con las primeras 50 lineas

```
Res       listA         listB       listC
1200         51           51          51
op           52           52          52
op           53           53          53
op           54           54          54
op           55           55          55
    .        .            .            .
    .        .            .            .
    .        .            .            .
op           100          100         100
```

otro .txt, con las siguientes 50 lineas:

```
Res        listA         listB       listC
1200         101           101          101
op           102           102          102
op           103           103          103
op           104           104          104
op           105           105          105
    .        .            .            .
    .        .            .            .
    .        .            .            .
op           150          150         150
```

Siendo el valor inicial 1200 en cada .txt

Comment: No veo dónde inicializas `op` ¿no tendría que ser `valor_Ini`?

Comment: Si, lo acabo de editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un truco típico para este tipo de situaciones es tomar el resto de la división de un contador entre una cantidad `N` y ver cuándo se hace cero. Eso indica que el contador se se ha hecho múltiplo de `N` y que toca cambiar algo.

En tu caso, cada 50 elementos quieres reiniciar `op`, si mal no entendí, pero ya que tu contador `i` comienza en 1 en vez de cero, deberás mirar cuándo el resto de dividir por 50 se hace 1.

```py
for i in range(1,long):
    if i % 50 == 1:
       op = 1200
    else:
        op -= (listaA[i]/listaA[i - 1]) + (2 + ((listaB[i-1]+listaB[i])/2)) / (c * d)
    lista_Res.append(round(op,3))
```

Un truco similar puede ser usado para lo de los ficheros, aunque la cosa se complica un poco más al tener que cerrar el fichero anterior y abrir uno nuevo cada vez que el contador se haga múltiplo de 50.

```py
contador = 0
dirFich = '/path'
salida = None     # Inicialmente no tenemos fichero abierto

for contador, j in enumerate(zip(lista_Res, listaA, listaB, listaC)):
    if contador % 50 == 0:  # Toca fichero nuevo
        # Cerramos el anterior, si había uno
        if salida:
            salida.close()
        # Abrimos el nuevo
        # Su nombre se basa en el contador, dividido por 50
        name = "{}/salida-{:03d}.txt".format(dirFich, contador//50)
        salida = open(dirFich + name,'w')

    out = ("{:> 19}" "{:> 13}" "{:> 19}".format(*j))
    # print(out)
    output += out + '\n'
    #salida.write(cabecera) 
    #salida.write(unidades)  
    salida.write(output)  

# Cerramos el último al salir
salida.close()
```

Comment: Estoy probando la parte de las operaciones, al operar obtengo los 50 primeros valores, pero el valor inicial tendría que ser 1200, es decir tendría que insertar en cada .txt como valor inicial de las operaciones el valor 1200.

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien lo que pides., pero creo que bastaría poner un `else:` delante de la línea que hace `op -= (formula)`. Es decir, cuando el contador llega a 51 (101, 151, etc) el valor de `op` será 1200 y en otro caso se computa con la fórmula dada

Comment: Si, era eso añadir un `else`, delante de la operación, una duda, en la parte de la escritura, inicias la variable `num_fichero = 1`, pero no la usas, y en `name` me podrías explicar como se utiliza, y muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ah, lo de `num_fichero` sobraría. Había pensado al principio usar esa variable como contador, pero después decidí mejor usar `enumerate()` sobre el `zip()`. Este `enumerate()` retorna tuplas siendo el primer elemento un contador y el segundo lo que habrías obtenido del `zip()`. El contador lo uso para saber cuándo hay que cambiar de fichero (cuando se haga múltiplo de 50) y para darle un nombre al fichero (el cociente entero de dividir entre 50). Uso `format` para crear ese nombre de fichero de modo que contenga ceros por delante, así: `salida-000.txt`, `salida-001.txt`, etc.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incorporar estos últimos cambios descritos en los comentarios

Comment: He quitado el `dirFich` en `salida = open(dirFich + name,'w')`, porque me estaba dando error,  intentaba escribir en una doble ruta, y ya esta funciona a la perfección, solo me falta añadir las cabeceras a cada fichero y estaría, gracias por todo **abulafia**, Un saludo.